# Only approach child element with certain class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get elements with a certain class from a list.

I roughly have the following html

```
<ul id="list">
<li class="1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="">
                <div class="text">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                    <img>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>Some more</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="">
                <div class="text">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                    <img>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>Some more</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="3">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
            <a href="">
                <div class="text">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                    <img>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>Some more</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to do change some classes on hover which only affect the elements that are children of the hovered element, but i can't get it working. So far i tried the following (all without the desired result):

```
$('ul#list li').hover(function(){
    // remove all previous active classes
    $(this).each('.text').removeClass('active');
```

```
// add active class to current item
$(this).children('.text').addClass('active');
$(this).next('.text').addClass('active');
$(this).closest('.text').addClass('active');
```

});

Does anybody has an idea how to approach this because i'm out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.text` divs aren't direct children of the list items you're hovering over, you need:

```
$(this).find('.text').toggleClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using `.hover()`, this function gets called when your mouse enters the element matched by the selector, but also when the mouse leaves. Try using `.mouseenter()`
2. You are using the `.each()` function where you seem to want a `.find()`.

   ```
   $(this).find('.text').removeClass('active');
   ```
3. You are using `.next()` with a selector, I think you want to find the text inside the next element, like so:

   ```
   $(this).next().find('.text').addClass('active');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul#list li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".text").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$('ul#list li').hover(function(){
    $('.text').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.text').addClass('active');
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/sKShf/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery children() method returns only children of a node one step down the DOM tree. To find all DOM items under a node that match a selector use the find()

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2VWvh/

```
$('ul#list li').hover(function(){
     // remove all pre`enter code here`vious active classes
    $('ul#list .text').removeClass('active');

    // add active class to current item
    $(this).find('.text').addClass('active');
});
```